# Multiple Auto Click on href Links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have read through various posts and searches online however have not got a solution as of yet. I have tried multiple articles here and elsewhere with little luck.

Situation: I have an accordion menu with members. I have some CSS and HTML working the image toggling. Meaning when you click a name is second col the image loads to the left in col 1.

Need: I need when page loads for each sections first image to load on page load.

I am using:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    document.getElementById("linkElement").click();
    });
```

However this only loads one ID. I am looking for a script to handle 5 ID tags via the href links.

```
<li><a href="#image1" class="mdrtf-link" id="linkElement">Various Names first link in list</a></li>
```

so to be clear there are five sections that when the page loads the first image should be auto loaded.

Also: I am using the CSS and HTML to toggle this. It looks like:

```
#output img {
display: none;
}

#output img:target {
display: inline;
}

#output-2 img {
display: none;
}

#output-2 img:target {
display: inline;
}
```

This CSS handles the toggle between the href links per photo.
I am open to JS or JQuery

Please let me know if you need more info. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it matters the site is done in Bootstrap 4

Comment: Ids are unique in HTML. In order to force click on every link you should loop trough the result of the collection returned by a class selector using getElementsByClassName.

Comment: Using that selector do you put classes in quotes, separated by commas... etc. ? Would you be so kind to show example?

Comment: A demo (codepen/jsfiddle) would help better understand the question.

Comment: HI @ Viney I am looking for a script that will auto on click 5 href links on page load via ID tag or class based on structure above.

Comment: What @Viney suggest is that you edit your post to put your code in a JSfiddle for better understanding. There is a button that let you create a snippet "<>".
So what you want is to load 5 images when a user load your website? A click is an action made by the user, so after your page is loaded, I don't understand what do you want to achieve here by using a click event in JS.